# How to deploy Nuxt in Universal Mode without Nginx?

Tags: deployment, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I followed the guidelines with the following steps:

1. Cloned project
2. Installed dependencies
3. Built project
4. Started project

I now have this insert:

```
   ╭────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                            │
   │   Nuxt.js v2.9.2                           │
   │   Running in production mode (universal)   │
   │   Memory usage: 25.9 MB (RSS: 70.4 MB)     │
   │                                            │
   │   Listening on: http://localhost:3000/     │
   │                                            │
   ╰────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Is there any kind of entry point to the app I could redirect the domain to?

Many tutorials suggest to install Nginx, however I don't have enough rights to do so on my hosting (Infomaniak managed cloud hosting).

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do it to figure out what http server that company is using and then **proxypass** requests on port 80 (for your domain) to localhost:3000

On Apache it's ProxyPass and for Nginx it's proxy_pass.

Comment: Thanks. Server is Debian 4.9 with Apache 2.4.34. I don't have any rights to change Apache config on this managed host... But I found Property Proxy Support in PHP. Is this related?

Comment: I don't think it's related. What Control panel is it? cPanel or some custom one? There should be a way to modify Apache configuration/virtual host... ?

Comment: It's a custom panel. For the Apache setting, I can only set environement variables and activate file compression. I'll guess I'll have to use another hosting solution...

Comment: Get yourself a VPS. I can recommend OVH and Contabo, I'm happy with both of them and they have some inexpensive packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the used port (3000) in the `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [L,P]
```

That's what Infomaniak [recommends doing](https://www.infomaniak.com/en/support/faq/2052/nodejs-support).

Additionally, they also have [an article on how to make a Node.js application run permanently with pm2](https://www.infomaniak.com/en/support/faq/2201/making-a-nodejs-application-run-permanently-on-a-cloud-server).

Comment: And if it's not disabled by default, you can also add `DirectoryIndex disabled` to the `.htaccess`. Otherwise, access to the root page might not work.